# Pulling data from multiple files and naming the data accordingly in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I am running that pulls data from numerous files within a folder and pastes the contents of that sheet in the file into one master file.  All the data is pasted in the master file correctly, however I need to have the name of the file the data was taken from pasted into the master file as well.

My macro is:

```
  Dim MyFile As String, Sep As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet, objwb As Workbook, objwb0 As Workbook
    Dim last_rowcurent As Long
    Dim last_row As Long
        Sheets("Warnings").Select
    last_rowcurent = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    Set objwb0 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wks1 = objwb0.Worksheets("Warnings")


  ' Sets up the variable "MyFile" to be each file in the directory
  ' This example looks for all the files that have an .xls extension.
  ' This can be changed to whatever extension is needed. Also, this
  ' macro searches the current directory. This can be changed to any
  ' directory.

  '' Test for Windows or Macintosh platform. Make the directory request.
  Sep = Application.PathSeparator

  'If Sep = "\" Then
     ' Windows platform search syntax.
     MyFile = Dir("P:\Frame\Frame_Piercing\Metrics_Development\Inmagusa\Warnings" & Sep & "*.xls")

  'Else

     ' Macintosh platform search syntax.
     'MyFile = Dir("", MacID("XLS5"))
  'End If

  ' Starts the loop, which will continue until there are no more files
  ' found.
  Do While MyFile <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

     ' Displays a message box with the name of the file. This can be
     ' changed to any procedure that would be needed to run on every
     ' file in the directory such as opening each file.
    last_rowcurent = wks1.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    Set objwb = Workbooks.Open("P:\Frame\Frame_Piercing\Metrics_Development\Inmagusa\Warnings" & Sep & MyFile)
    Set wks2 = objwb.Worksheets("navistar-warnings")
        Sheets("navistar-warnings").Select
    last_row = wks2.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("A2")) Then



        'MsgBox last_row
        wks2.Range("A2:h" & last_row).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks("Inmagusa_Merge_Files.xlsm").Activate
        Worksheets("Warnings").Range("A1").Select
        'Sheets("Errors").Select
        last_rowcurent = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & last_rowcurent).Select
        'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Release").Range("A" & lastrowcurent).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=x1PasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

        'wks1.Range("A" & last_rowcurent).PasteSpecial(Paste:=x1PasteValues, Paste:=x1PasteFormats, Operation:= _
        x1None, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)
        'wks1.Range("A" & last_rowcurent).Select
        'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, x1PasteFormats, Operation:= _
        'xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        'wks2.Range("A4:w" & last_row).Copy
        'wks1.Range("A" & last_rowcurent).Select
        'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        'SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        'Workbooks("Frame_WorkPlanning_Master.xlsm").Activate
        'last_rowcurent = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Release").Range("A3").Row
        'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Release").Range("a3").Paste
           'With wks1.Range("A" & last_rowcurent)
               '.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
               '.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
               '.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue
                'or other parameters...
           'End With
    End If
       objwb.Close False


     'MsgBox "P:\Frame\Work_Planning\Engineer_Plans" & Sep & MyFile
     MyFile = Dir()
  Loop
'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Release").Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
False, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:= _
```

I need the file name pasted in column 'I' but the amount of rows varies with the data in each separate file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of code that is commented out which make it a little difficult to follow.  I ignored all the commented code and rewrote the part in question to eliminate `Active` & `Select`.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) to learn more about why this is a good idea.

The file name is now printed in column `I` on the first row of new data being pasted

```
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks("Inmagusa_Merge_Files.xlsm")

If Not IsEmpty(Range("A2")) Then
    wks2.Range("A2:h" & last_row).Copy

    last_rowcurent = wbSource.Worksheets("Warnings").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

    ' Put file name in Column I on the first row of new data
    wbSource.Worksheets("Warnings").Range("I" & last_rowcurent).Value = objwb.Name

    wbSource.Worksheets("Warnings").Range("A" & last_rowcurent).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End If
```

---

**EDIT**

To paste the name in Column I for every row of new data you can loop like this:

```
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks("Inmagusa_Merge_Files.xlsm")

If Not IsEmpty(Range("A2")) Then
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Set copyRange = wks2.Range("A2:h" & last_row)

    copyRange.Copy

    last_rowcurent = wbSource.Worksheets("Warnings").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

    ' Put file name in Column I on the first row of new data
    'wbSource.Worksheets("Warnings").Range("I" & last_rowcurent).Value = objwb.Name

    ' Put file name in Column I for every row being pasted
    For j = 1 + last_rowcurent To copyRange.Rows.Count + last_rowcurent
        wbSource.Worksheets("Warnings").Range("I" & j).Value = objwb.Name
    Next j

    wbSource.Worksheets("Warnings").Range("A" & last_rowcurent).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End If
```

Note that I commented out the single line code and added in a For loop to print the name for every cell.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am just starting with this stuff, so a little unfamiliar with it all - Where does this portion go within my current text?

Comment: Take my code and use it to replace everything After `last_row = wks2.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row` and `Before objwb.Close False`

Comment: Awesome, works great!!  Thank you so much.  Last question would be if there is a way to get it to paste to all rows of the data that it is being pulled from in column I?

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I edited my answer to include the ability to print the name on every row for the data being pasted.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help with this.  Currently, I am using this code and it is not pulling the last file in the folder, and when pasting the file names it pastes one row under the last row.  I will keep playing around with it, but if you have any additional advice I would greatly appreciate it.